# How to force build on another widget?

Tags: flutter

I have orange and green Ball objects and the Offset of both are passed to both the Ball objects as constructor. Moving orange ball, how do force green ball to move? I can change offset but how do I force the green Ball instance to build itself? I am using Stack widget.

```
 FullState State = FullState.fullParam(Offset(000, 150), Offset(000, 10));//offset of both the Balls
//first offset for orange and second offset for green ball.



 @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      children: <Widget>[
    Ball(state,, 'green', AssetImage('images/greenBall.png')),
    Ball(state,, 'orange', AssetImage('images/orangeBall.png')),
```

Comment: Try to pass a NotificationListener to your widgets, wrap your balls in consumers so they can rebuild when you update the value of one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped the state in ChangeNotifier and used a custom method with notifyListeners() instead. (Agreed it is clunky but it works)

```
class State extends ChangeNotifier {..

someMethod(updatedState){
//decorate state if necessary
notifyListeners();}
```